# Lorentzian geometry. Comparing Honda's main theorem A construction to mine: Mixed type surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

This question is based on a wonderful paper by A. Honda (link below) where his main theorem A provides an incredible uniqueness result. Mixed type surfaces and type changing metrics have been intensively studied from both a mathematical and theoretical physics point of view. I am specifically interested in Honda's theorem A for this question:

[image]

My construction following suit of theorem A:

Consider a finite family $\Psi_\alpha$ where $\alpha=1,2,3,4$ of mutually transversely intersecting mixed type surfaces of $\mathbf L^3$ (Lorentz-Minkowski $3$-space) inscribed in $[-1,1]^3.$ Let the $\Psi_\alpha$ have the same first fundamental form, Gaussian curvature $+1$, and be surfaces of revolution. A mixed type surface is a surface in $\mathbf L^3$ whose spacelike, timelike and lightlike point sets are non-empty. Lightlike points may be regarded as singular points of the induced metric. The mutual transversal intersection of the $\Psi_\alpha$ partitions $\mathbf L^3$ into $9$ compact $3$ cells and $1$ non-compact $3$ cell. Take $S$ to be the boundary of the non-compact $3$ cell. Then define a causal structure on $S$ by letting $-1\le z<0$ be the past, $z=0$ to be the present and $0<z \le 1$ to be the future. As a result $3$ closed loops on $S$ are apparent and the slice $z=0$ is a closed loop representing the present using our $+z$ timelike orientation.

> Is $S$ indeed a mixed type surface? How does this compare to Honda's intersecting $f_i$ surfaces that share a common space-like Frenet curve?

Reference: [Isometric deformations of mixed type surfaces in Lorentz-Minkowski space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01967), by A. Honda. (specifically Theorem A, page 3, figure 2).

[image]

Supplementary construction:

Consider $\chi(\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^4 \bar M_{\alpha})=0$ where $\bar M_{\alpha}$ are geodesic compactifications of $S^1 \times \mathbf R$ resp. for some 'nice' non-empty mutual intersection. We have $N:=\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^4 \bar M_{\alpha}$ which we'll view as topologically indistinguishable from the stellated octahedron, which carries a vanishing Euler characteristic. Is it reasonable to expect this compact Lorentzian manifold $(N,g)$, say it's embedded in $\mathbf L^3$ with signature $(++-)$, behaves as a global Lorentzian manifold for which the induced metric $g$ becomes singular at the smooth singular loci?

I think the construction I'm dealing with just presents a different topology for the four intersecting mixed type surfaces. I trade Honda's surfaces for a different, more symmetrical type.